# how to optimize Flip,Reverse and Rotate of an image?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, optimization

i have different method which will perform flip , reverse and rotate (by 90deg) operation.
since i need to apply these operation for several images in sequence i would like to optimize it..for eg. if i rotate by 90 twice and i reverse once an image it is equal to perform flip operation..but i can't find it to be in an particular sets of combinations.. if i do flip rotate reverse rotate flip rotate reverse rotate and go on is giving me an uncertain result..

> for now i am optimizing by cancelling the operation for 2 flip 2 reverse and 4 rotate but when operating in random order like above i am unable to track it...

is there is any algorithm can be applicable for this or any flip rotate and reverse combination sequence using which i can optimize the operation for sequence of images

THANKS IN ADVANCE

note: flip is vertical , reverse is mirror image and rotate is by 90deg clockwise

Comment: Is your question about applying a single transform to each image or a predefined series of transforms to each image ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am right, there are just 7 possible different operations in addition to identity (90, 180, 270 rotations and 0, 90, 180, 270 rotations followed by mirroring). For good efficiency, it is better to code them explicitly rather than use combinations that will double or triple the time.

If you really want to implement few functions and combine them, 2 primitives are necessary and sufficient: for example rotate by 90 (R) and mirror (|).

```
   0 => abcd => 
  90 => dabc => R
 180 => cdab => R R
 270 => bcda => R R R

  0| => badc => |
 90| => adcb => R |
180| => dcba => R R |
270| => cbad => | R
```

The corners are listed clockwise from top-left. As you said, flip is 180|.

By supporting an extra primitive operation, + (central symmetry or rotation by 180), you always do in at most 2 operations:

```
   0 => 
  90 => R
 180 => +
 270 => + R

  0| => |
 90| => R |
180| => + |
270| => | R
```

Working with rotate, flip and mirror, you cannot avoid triple combinations.

Answer (score 2):

Write down matrices of affine transformation for all operations mentioned.
Multiply them in order of operations, and resulting matrix is what you need.

Comment: all the transform are done already in method i just need to reduce calling of it..thanks a lot for spending  u r time....

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good application for a [planner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_planning_and_scheduling)! Or, in other words, search the shortest path in a graph. The nodes are image configurations and two nodes are connected if you can go from one to another by applying a certain transformation (rotate, flip, or reverse).

The starting point is a normal image and the goal node is the one which has the desired configuration, i.e. the one you reach after applying in order all the given operations. You can use an algorithm such as [Breatdh First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the path. The edges of the found path are the transformations you need to do.

Comment: haven't heard of these algos that you are talking about. will give it a look. thanks for giving a look to my post. BTW i got the answer I wanted from yves Daoust. Will give a look  sir after my project is completed